# html5/js: filling ring on slide

Tags: jquery, css, html, gestures

i'd like to fill and empty a html div on slide up and down.
if the user slides up on the #screen the #ring filling increases and if he slides down,
it decreases. see the figure: http://imageshack.com/a/img607/5898/zdpv.jpg

hope you can help :)

```
<div id="screen" style="position:absolute; with:100%; heigh:100%;"></div>
<div id="ring" style="height:500px; width:500px; border:2px solid #000000; border-radius: 50%;"></div>
```

Comment: check out http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this.

HTML

```
<div id="ring" style="">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the #content is the black div that will change with the mouse. Next you've the css associated to the html.

CSS

```
#ring {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px; 
    width:200px; 
    border:2px solid #000000; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top:200px;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;    
    background-color:#000;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Finally, the javascript. I used jquery to do the variations about height. As you can see, I've made the variations with the mouse movement. Take a look and if it's what are you looking for, you only have to apply some script or some change to make it works for smartphone or tablet or some touchable device.

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#ring").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        var p_of = $(this).parent().offset();        
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        mouse_y = $(this).height() - e.pageY + offset.top;
        $("#content").css({'height' : mouse_y});
    });   
});
```

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/zFHLQ/), so you can change whatever you want.

Comment: Looks good but it doesnt work on touch - smartphone. is it possible to make it touchable? so that the filling changes on slide up and slide down?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `clip`

http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/D9Xwj/

HTML:

```
<div id="circle">
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    $('#circle').css({
        "clip": "rect(" + e.pageY + "px,204px,204px,0px)"
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#circle {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid #330099;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #330099;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Explanation: as you move the mouse the top value of the [clipping rectangle](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) is changed to the current mouse position.